# serve pre-compressed files with Starlette, when uncompressed is requested, but 'accept-encoding' includes 'gzip'

Tags: python, gzip, starlette

Assuming as `request.url`

```
GET /fomantic-ui/default/semantic.min.css
```

for certain file extension, e.g. `.css`, I need to serve a pre-compressed `.gz` version.

From node-express I know an approach, that when applied to Starlette would be to simply manipulate the `request.url.path` and append a `'.gz'` to it. However that results in an `AttributeError: Can't set attribute`.

What would be the approach in the Starlette world?

Only thing I've found, is a middleware that should handle GZIP requests. But I think it's not usable here, because I need my own logic to decide what file to request from an AWS S3 bucket or a `diskcache`.

Here is an example of the route handler:

```py
async def theme(request):
  try:
    file_path = request.path_params.get('file_path')
    is_asset = file_path.split('.')[-1] in ['ico', 'png']
    if is_asset:
      full_path = f'assets/{file_path}'
    else:
      if 'gzip' in request.headers['accept-encoding']:
        full_path = f'theme_build/{file_path}.gz'
        request.url.path = request.url.path + '.gz' # results in AttributeError("can't set attribute")
      else:
        full_path = f'theme_build/{file_path}'
    print(full_path, flush=True)
    s3_result = get_file(full_path)
    return StreamingResponse(s3_result['Body'], headers=s3_result['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders'])
  except ...
```

Obviously I can't just return the gzipped content as a response to the original `request.url`, as the browser won't expect gzipped content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the right way to do this at all is to set `'content-encoding': 'gzip'` in the header of the response.

So, in the example above I basically do:

```
return StreamingResponse(
    s3_result['Body'],
    headers={**s3_result['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders'], 'content-encoding': 'gzip'}
)
```